# java 8 compare datetime, with zoned time

Tags: java, time

How do I check if request is in between this window? I have a time of request as 2011-12-03T15:15:30-05:00 and a time window which could be defined in any zone, example 09:00:00+00:00 and 17:00:00+00:00.

Now if i parse the datetime to LocalTime i loose the timezone.

```
public LocalTime time(String time){

    return LocalTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_TIME.parse(time));
}



private ZonedDateTime dateTime(String dateTime){
    return ZonedDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(dateTime));
}
```

//Compare function

```
public boolean compare(ZonedDateTime dateTime, LocalTime localTime, LocalTime localTime2) {

    LocalTime time = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utc).toLocalTime();


    int start = time.compareTo(localTime);
    int end = time.compareTo(localTime2);

    return start >= 0 && end <= 0;

}
```

now i invoke the above compare function as:

```
service.compare(dateTime("2011-12-03T15:15:30-05:00"), time("09:00:00+00:00"), time("17:00:00+00:00"));
```

Comment: That's not really a `ZonedDateTime` - it's an `OffsetDateTime`. (It doesn't specify a time zone, just an offset from UTC.) But it's not clear how the parsing relates to the comparsion part. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just one snippet which only talks about a small part of what you're doing.

Comment: i have added the comparison function which is flawed based on my requirements

Comment: `09:00:00+00:00` is not a `LocalTime`. Do you want to simply check if the `ZonedDateTime` value has a time between 9 AM and 5 PM, ignoring time zone, or (since you said window can "be defined in any zone") do you want to account for time zone differences? Assuming the latter, you need to know the zone of the window too, which you've lost by using `LocalTime`. Use `OffsetTime` instead.

Comment: That's still not a [mcve] - and you haven't clearly expressed your requirements. (You start off talking about the window being in "any zone" but then you're passing in LocalTime values...) You're also converting the `ZonedDateTime` to UTC for no obvious reason. If you can't clearly express what you're trying to do, it's going to be very hard to help you. I suspect you'll find that when you *have* worked out how to express what you want to do, the code will be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of code that will compare a `ZonedDateTime` value in any time zone, to see if it falls within a time-of-day window define in another (or same) time zone, correctly adjusting for the time zone difference.

Notice that time window values are now `OffsetTime`, not `LocalTime`, so the window time zone offset is known.

Also notice that this code was change to be upper-exclusive, which is generally what you want for range comparisons like this.

```
public static boolean inWindow(ZonedDateTime dateTime, OffsetTime windowStart, OffsetTime windowEnd) {
    if (! windowStart.getOffset().equals(windowEnd.getOffset()))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("windowEnd must have same offset as windowStart");
    OffsetTime time = dateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
                              .withOffsetSameInstant(windowStart.getOffset())
                              .toOffsetTime();
    return (! time.isBefore(windowStart) && time.isBefore(windowEnd));
}
```

Comment: thanks, whats the purpose of check:
 if (! windowStart.getOffset().equals(windowEnd.getOffset()))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("windowEnd must have same offset as windowStart")

Comment: I now have the method, below which seems to work
public boolean compare(ZonedDateTime dateTime, OffsetTime startTime, OffsetTime endTime) {

  
  OffsetTime offsetTime = dateTime.toOffsetDateTime().toOffsetTime();
  
  int start = offsetTime.compareTo(startTime);
  int end = offsetTime.compareTo(endTime);

  return start >= 0 && end <= 0;

 }